# In Visual Studio Code, what is the MOST correct/authoritative filename and location for tasks.json if it is to be checked into source control?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has a file for defining custom build tasks.  However, Microsoft is highly inconsistent about the correct name and location of this file in their documentation.

In theory, this document-- updated FEB2019-- is the most correct again:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

This seems to specify

${workspaceRoot}/tasks.vs.json

as the most correct name if the file is to be checked into source code control, and the hidden

${workspaceRoot}/.vs/tasks.vs.json

otherwise.  However, the C++ language support documentation for Visual Studio code here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

...names this file with a second name, and a THIRD directory:

.vscode/tasks.json

I'm used to Microsoft failing to keep documentation up to date because they don't use macros that propagate to update existing docs, but in this case, I'm not getting the results I need from any combination of this stuff, so I'm unable to determine what is authoritative.  I can't debug both that and my JSON at the same time, for obvious reasons.

Can somebody tell me what the MOST CORRECT, MOST CURRENT name and location for this file should be, if I intend to use it with Code's C++ support, and track it in subversion?